# How to enable different colors with ls on Mac?

Tags: bash

I've noticed when I ssh into a server the bash output is a lot more colorful. For instance, using `$ ls` will display directories as blue and recognised files as green. How do I get this functionality working on a Mac?

Comment: Have you checked if `man ls` mentions `color`/`colour`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks, it mentions `CLICOLOR` and `LSCOLORS`, adding `export CLICOLOR=1` to *.bashrc* did the trick

Comment: You can [write an answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) then.

Answer (score 1):

The command `ls -G` gives you a colorized output .

To avoid having to type `-G` everytime you use it, You can modify  *.bashrc* with:

```
alias ls='ls -G'
alias ll='ls -lG'
```

Comment: Is there much difference between using `alias ls='ls -G'` and `export CLICOLOR=1`?

Comment: @ryanedwards Other tools may react to `CLICOLOR=1`. I think the very point of this variable is to [inform all tools you want colored output](https://bixense.com/clicolors/) (some tools may not care though). When writing your own program/script you may choose to implement colored output according to the variable as well. So it's like a global option.